# action code for taking pictures

Tags: android

im trying to take a picture inside an android app, and im trying to use the android devloper tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

they bring the following code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}
```

i can't understand what is this action code and what it should be for taking pictures
thanks!

Comment: There is quite a few things you have to learn to understand the code: the concept of activities, intents and tasks. When you read up on then, come back to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html), the second parameter to `startActivityForResult` is used to distinguish between multiple different requests (say, if you got results from both the camera and the gallery you'd want to know where the result is from).

That same `actionCode` is then returned as the `requestCode` in `onActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

The point is that it doesn't matter exactly what the number is (0, 1, 100, 5439, whatever), only that it is unique within your `Activity`. Therefore if you are only calling `startActivityForResult` in one place for one result, any number will do (as there is nothing to conflict with)

Answer (score 0):

Intents are designed to allow your application to interact with others. In this case, your application will bring up the camera app, and the result will be sent back into your app.

A great place to get started with understanding this is, is the Android training ["Interacting with Other Apps"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html).